# Shift+Insert clipboard only working one way between two Emacs instances

Tags: emacs, clipboard

I have two Emacs instances running, one locally and the other as an X Window running on a server I am ssh-connected to. When I try to copy+paste text between one and the other, the instance running on the server can paste to the local one by selecting text and doing <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, then doing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> on the local Emacs buffer. But the other way doesn't work: by selecting text and doing <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> on the local Emacs then doing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> on the server Emacs, I get either nothing, or the contents of the clipboard from another program (e.g. the browser).

I have the same .emacs file on both, so I am not sure what's making these behave differently. How can I make the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> pasting work from local to server Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me. Try adding the following into `.emacs` on the remote machine:

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```